# API Management service in Bluemix can't be bound to CF application

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-api-management

I'm building a CloudFoundry application in Bluemix using the API Management service. For this I'm following this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-api-mgmt-app/index.html.

I can successfully create an API Plan for a custom REST API application (running on a Liberty server on Bluemix as well) and it is published.

I can also create a service in my Bluemix dashboard using the new Custom API, which I take as the API plan was successfully deployed on Bluemix.

Whenever I try to bind this new service I get the following message:

> BXNUI2055E: Unable to connect to Cloud Foundry because of the
>   following exception: "Read timed out." If the problem persists, see
>   the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check
>   service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information
>   about getting help.

From time to time I also get this message

> The service broker returned an invalid response for the request to
>   https://apimasv1-stage.stage1.mybluemix.net/d118dceb-edbf-4a7f-9bab-d44371b0c9f9/privateservices/v2/service_instances/1a60830c-0796-4105-afb4-e3477424acf9/service_bindings/ebb853dc-ec88-4987-b8f2-e9acd38d1741.
>   Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway, Body: 502 Bad Gateway: Registered
>   endpoint failed to handle the request.

Also, I can open the API portal and see the services listed in there. However, whenever I try to test the service, I get the following error

> A security error has occurred. If using a self-signed certificate on
>   your gateway, you will need to accept it in your browser, which you
>   can do by clicking the following link.
>   https://api.wawona.apim.ibmcloud.com/victorshmx1ibmcom-dev/sb/LibraryREST/rs/authors/1

Also, below in the response I get this message:

> NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to
>   load
>   'https://api.wawona.apim.ibmcloud.com/victorshmx1ibmcom-dev/sb/LibraryREST/rs/authors/1'.

I must clarify this service (the liberty app) doesn't have any security constraint to access the REST service nor I added some kind of security in the API Management portal.

Another thing to clarify is that I can bind other services, but not this one.

Does anyone know how I can fix those problems? Is there a known issue with IBM API Management service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be an error with the service API Management instance you are trying to bind to.
You could open a ticket to support team following the link you can find here:
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/

Click on 'Contact IBM' and open a 'Support ticket'

Comment: Hi v.bontempi.
Yes, it turned out to be a problem on the backend wiring in Bluemix. I was able to successfully bind the service to my application after some issues got resolved